# How to validate Powershell Desired State Configuration Template before Executing?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

As we provision certain resources in Azure, management portal validates the template generated, however when we do it using powershell we only come to know about issues, only when it is executed.

> There must be some parameter or switch which could help to just
>   validate the template & not actually execute it. Any body knows
>   please?

Comment: Use `Get-Help Your-Command` to check if there is a `-WhatIf` or `-Confirm` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about deploying ARM templates and I also assume you are using the AzureRm PowerShell module. In that case you can use the `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` command to 'Validates a resource group deployment' (from the command's help).